# Is it possible to retrieve access keys from a AWS user using his login information?

Tags: php, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to build a project to help users manage their S3 account. To do this, however, it requires them to manually provide me with their access key. It's complicated though, and I'd like to make it easier for them.

Is there a way that I can retrieve their access keys by using their login information?

I'd prefer if the solution was in PHP, but it's not an obligation.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe selenium could be a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out a way to make it work. Basically, I've set up a Selenium Webdriver server and downloaded all required C# files. I then created this little script:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IWebDriver driver;
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://aws-portal.amazon.com/gp/aws/securityCredentials");
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("ap_email")).Clear();
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("ap_email")).SendKeys("USER@EMAILACCOUNT.COM");
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("ap_password")).Clear();
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("ap_password")).SendKeys("HISPASSWORD");
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("signInSubmit")).Click();

        IList<IWebElement> keys = driver.FindElements(By.LinkText("Show"));
        int nbElems = keys.Count;
        System.Console.WriteLine(nbElems+" keys");
        foreach (IWebElement k in keys)
        {
            String toparse = k.GetAttribute("href");
            Regex regex = new Regex(@"'(?<key>.*)','(?<secret>.*)'");

            GroupCollection groups = regex.Match(toparse).Groups;

            System.Console.WriteLine(groups["key"] + " " + groups["secret"]);
        }

        driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Sign Out")).Click();
        driver.Quit();
    }
```

Now I just need to find a way to send the user information safely to this script.

Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: `Now I just need to find a way to send the user information safely to this script.`... that is highly non-trivial to get right. Be very careful.

Comment: My idea is this: My machine running this script is different than my webserver. My Webserver has SSL encryption. I was thinking that maybe I could retrieve "key retrieval tasks" from that server using an HTTPS GET request. The data would be encrypted using asymetric keys and openssl. Sounds reasonable?

Answer (score 0):

**If S3 buckets are for users in your account**

If you're talking about access keys associated to users in an account that you countrol, have a look at *AWS Identity and Access Management* / [ListAccessKeys](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/API_ListAccessKeys.html).

> IAM [ Identity and Access Management] is a web service that enables
>   AWS customers to manage users and user permissions under their AWS
>   account

**If S3 buckets are for an account that you do not own**

If you're talking about an access key associated with someone else's AWS account (as well as per your comment the secret key), [according to AWS](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSecurityCredentials/1.0/AboutAWSCredentials.html#AccessKeys) you can only get the access key from the Access Keys tab on the AWS Security Credentials page.

This makes perfect sense, as the access key is a protected account secret.  Providing an API to retrieve secrets would not make sense.

Additionally, if a user provided you with their account credentials, that would be an enormous security issue.  You could spin up any AWS resources you wanted and they would be liable.  Even if they trusted you 100% not to do that, if you allow that login data to be hacked, the hacker could do the same.  If [LinkedIn login data can be hacked](http://money.cnn.com/2012/06/06/technology/linkedin-password-hack/index.htm), you can be hacked too.

Comment: You are right. I know there are huge security concerns for this. But if you take for example Mint.com, that website is able to login to your bank account even if there's no API. I suppose they are using some form or web browser automation, though I'm not certain. That's the kind of stuff I'd like to do!

Comment: Yeah, you'll probably need some sort of automation tool to do this. Something like Selenium, Zombie.js, etc, but for PHP.

Comment: Oh wow, Zombie.js is pretty sweet! Do you know any similar framework for jQuery?

Comment: Do you mean using it in/on an iFrame? There would be issues with cross domain access in an iFrame like that. Zombie doesn't have that issue because it creates its own "virtual browser." And yeah, it's pretty cool :) Just started using it myself on a project.

Comment: Mint.com is owned by Intuit.  If you don't have a similar reputation (and a similar IT organization to handle security), you cannot compare this to what mint.com is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Given the the user name you can list the users accesskeys using [ListAccessKeys](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/API_ListAccessKeys.html) api.

But there seems to a catch in your problem. In order to use the above api you will need to sign the request with an accesskey - secret pair. And I dont think you will have they coz you are building a tool for other other unless the users in your aws account and full permission atleast on s3 and iam.

Then again this will allow you get only the accesskeys not their secret. Asking for the secret is like asking someone for their password so that you can do something on their behalf. So you can't get the secret from the aws through any api, the only way to get it is if the user gives it to you.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but that only gives me the access key? I need the secret key as well if I want to be able to sign URLS and manage their buckets :S